# I want to get value from other cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get value from other cs file.

for example. there are two cs files in same Project. 
one is A.cs, another is B.cs

And there is a variable in A.cs

```
int a = 1;
```

i want to use variable 'a' in B.cs, like this

```
int b = a;
```

then what should i do?

Comment: Whether a variable/field is accessible or not doesn't depend on the file in which it is, it depends on the structures that surround the variables/fields. Please provide source code for both files and we can help you.

Comment: Google is always your best friend. https://www.google.by/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=asp%20passing%20variables%20between%20pages

Comment: To those who want to answer - maybe you should wait until you know what the _question_ is? We can't tell if the OP knows _anything_ about C#. The fact that he's talking about "files" suggests maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try making your variables static then you can access it any other file

Here is Explanation:

First file: A.cs

```
class A
{
   public static int a=4;
}
```

Secound file: B.cs

```
class B
{
   public int b=A.a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same namespace you will need to change the default access modifier to allow access. I believe the default is protected. More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

You would need to change int a = 1 to something like

```
internal class ClassA
{
        internal int a = 2;
}
```

then you would instiate a from b

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
b = classA.a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A 
{
public int intA = 1;
}
```

now, call it in B.cs

```
public class B
{
A = new A();
var valueA = A.intA;
}
```